# Bathroom exhaust fan and light

Tags: electrical, bathroom, exhaust

I just got bathroom fan and light.

Only my light is working. Is there any way I can splice the fan wire with the light.

I only have two wires on my switch and I don’t want to run a new wire.

[image]

Comment: Why is the cable not running into the hole in the fan enclosure, first off?  Is it not long enough to reach...?

Comment: Wow. There appears to be several things that do not make sense or are  wrong with that wiring job. did you do this? If so please provide a detailed description of exactly what you have done here.

Comment: No it’s the original wiring to the house. The wire is not long enough to com to the back side of the hole.

Comment: It’s was a single pole light switch. And got a fan with light. And thought there was enough wires to run the light and fan. But only the light comes  on. Is there anyone around not running new wire up the wall. Like if I cut the wire to the fan and splice to the light wire?

Comment: Is there room for a junction box in the ceiling on the opposite side of the fan? Can you tell if that NM cable is 14AWG or 12AWG for that matter?

Comment: "*The wire is not long enough to com to the back side of the hole*"  The wire appears to be long enough. I can see it enter from lower left, no?  Can you rotate the fan so the knockout for the wire is on the opposite side, This would also put the mounting tabs on the housing on structure for attaching it. (*how is the fan attached for that matter?*)  On you wire, it shows the black fan wire to the white house wire, Usually the white is the neutral, did you test the wires to see if the tan is hot or the white?